# How do I run visual basic script from visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

The script is used to enable or disable LAN. I would like to run it from a VB application by integrating it.  Could someone help please?

Comment: sry about that im using visual basic 2010

Comment: Even in 2010 there are still at least 3 active VB dialects - VBScript (mostly found in webpages or .vb script files), VB.NET (developed from Visual Studio) and VBA (integrated in MS Office). Do you mean VB.NET?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, assuming VB6 since you didn't tag it as VB.NET

```
Dim wsh
wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wsh.run("C:\Scripts\test.vbs", 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

VBScript is (almost) a subset of VB.

You can copy your VBScript code directly into the VB source.

If you have any trouble, please ask a specific question.